# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'weekday'

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I tried running linear regressions in Jupyter and it is throwing me a strange "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'weekday'" error. Any ideas?

```
for df in [lr_train, lr_test]:
    df['day_of_week'] = df.index.weekday
    df['is_weekend'] = df.index.map(lambda x: 1 if x.weekday() > 4 else 0)
    df['hour_of_day'] = df.index.hour
    df['time_since_jan'] = df.index.map(lambda x: time_since_start(x))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This means that the object you're attempting to get the `.weekday` attribute from does not have that attribute. Given the code, it appears that `df['day_of_week']` is a string and not a `datetime.datetime()` object.

If you want to see why this is happening, try the following code in a Python terminal.

```py
from datetime import datetime

current = datetime.now()
current_string = current.isoformat()

print(current.weekday)

print(current_string)

print(current_string.weekday)
```

The last line will throw the same exception you're seeing.

Comment: print(current.weekday) throws an error. Instead, it should be print(current.weekday())

Comment: No, it doesn't throw an error. Try the code for yourself.